# SQL Server Performance option(recompile) and Renaming variables

Tags: sqlperformance

We have several procedures in an enterprise application that are exhibiting weird behavior. Some of the procedures get 'stuck' and never return, running for hours on the large databases. We were able to replicate this behavior on some of our test databases. What is weird is that we can get the procedure to run and return almost instantly by renaming some of the variables passed in, or we discovered using option(recompile) has the same effect. What I find weird is that after doing that, databases that are very small seem to get stuck and never return. So it seems we can get them to work on the small but not the large, or on the large but not the small. I need some suggestions as to what to look for. This is happening in several stored procedures.

Procedure layout is:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[proc_sample_proc]
  @var1     guid
, @var2     guid = null
, @var3     guid
, @var4     guid
, @var5         varchar(20) = null
, @var6     varchar(20) = null
as

if  @var1 = @var2
set @var2 = null

DECLARE @var7
SELECT @var7 = dbo.udf_TTTT_GetSOMEUDF(@var4)

SELECT
//somefields
FROM
atable
INNER JOIN btable ON a=b
LEFT JOIN ctable on (nolock) b=@var3
LEFT JOIN dtable on c=d
LEFT JOIN etable on d=e
LEFT JOIN ftable on (nolock) e=@var4
INNER JOIN gtable on f=g
LEFT JOIN htable on g=h
WHERE @var1=somevalue AND @var5=anothervalue
ORDER BY somefields

OPTION(RECOMPILE) <-- I Know this is BAD
```

Comment: how are you using the parameters var1, var2..etc in the select statement? or are you not?

Comment: They are used in the joins and where clause